# Getting Facebook Targeting Ids

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

We were getting targeting IDs from Facebook from this location:

http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/targeting_ids.json

Unfortunately it is now giving us a 404 when we try to access it.  We did find a copy of it hosted here: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/File:Targeting_ids.json.txt however we were looking to access this directly from Facebook.

Is there another location or another way to get the list of targeting Ids for City, State, Region and Language?  We were using these IDs to target new fan page wall posts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation that static file is long-deprecated; you should be getting your targeting info directly from the API.

Instructions for doing so (with examples) are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

Comment: The reason we were not originally using this is because it is part of the ads api and we are targeting new fan page wall posts.  I'm going to run some tests on the information that is returned from this to see if it will work in place.

Comment: oh, gotcha, I forgot about page post targeting; That endpoint should work even if you're not in the Marketing API Program, I just tested getting countries back using an app that isn't in the program and it worked successfully

Comment: Ok, this seems to be giving back the same information (up to date which is great!).  Is an access token required to access this API information?  I've been testing it and without the access token it is still giving me back data.

Comment: It's documented as needing an access token; even if it works without one i'd recommend using one in case it changes sometime

Comment: "According to the documentation that static file is long-deprecated"  Would you be able to point me in the direction of the documentation that you're referring to?  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, i can't seem to find it, but nor can i find where we reference the file- i work with the ads API, where this used to be used but was replaced with the search i mentioned above - are we still linking to the .json file in some of the docs?

Answer (score 0):

I went to Google and searched for 'targeting_ids.json' and found several different archive sites where you can [get a copy](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/File%3aTargeting_ids.json.txt)